# Running Drupal 7 website without database

Tags: php, linux, database, drupal-7

I have developed a beautiful website in Drupal 7. During hosting it to main server, I realized that the server doesn't have any database facility in it. It has php support only. I want to host the website here.

I found some converter to convert php into html but this doesn't seems a good choice.

Somebody please tell me the better options for this scenario.

Comment: Change the provider?

Comment: @choroba: I know that is the simplest and easiest option. But since I have posted the question here, that means I have some limitations/restrictions in this option.

Answer (score 2):

If you had another server or access to another platform that does have Database technology, you could just use that as the database host. They don't have to be located on the same host. Look up services such as: [FreeMysql Hosting](http://www.freemysqlhosting.net)

A google for "mysql host" would turn up quite a few options

With that said, I'd just move host as earlier suggested

Comment: `FreeMySQL hosting` !!! Just wanted to ask you that are these servers reliable?

Comment: Sorry to say, I can't testify for any of these free SQL hosts, just that external DB hosting is an option and that showed up at the top of a Google search. A general rule in life is that you get what you pay for though

Answer (score 0):

It is apparently [possible](https://groups.drupal.org/node/10282) to use some flat files instead of a database layer but it is not recommanded at all because of many aspects, space, performance, security, etc.... Some people are saying that every single people who has used flat files for BD and/or content management has regretted it in the end.

As choroba said, change provider to get a DB.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. But at this moment I can't change the host. That is the main limitation from my side.